# discordjs role.members.has() takes over 100ms to execute

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a role with about 650 members in it, I'm trying to find if my given member id is in the members of that role.

I'm doing:

`role.members.has(id)` (or `role.members.get(id)`) in a loop, for some smaller sets it takes less than 5ms. With collections of 500+ it takes 100ms+ for each check, which is way too long for a simple `.get`, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`role.members` getter](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/2f6f365098cbab397cda124711c4bb08da850a17/src/structures/Role.js#L198-L200) is an O(n) operation which is why your current code is performing poorly:

```js
get members() {
  return this.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has(this.id));
}
```

Like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70568546/10808983) says, you should instead be fetching the member directly and then checking for the role with [`GuildMemberRoleManager.cache.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager).

Fetching a member by ID and then checking their cached roles are all O(1) operations which should be much more performant.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the code, that's what I suspected. I just created my own map from the collection once, and I access it in my loop with O(1). That avoids to `await` and make more calls as well.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt guaranteed to work any more efficiently but I would assume fetching the member and checking that specific members roles would be more efficient than filtering cache.

```js
const member = await <Guild>.members.fetch(id);
if(member.roles.cache.has(<Role>){
  ...
};
```